# How can I create a two column per page print layout?

Tags: css, printing

I have a long content block. What I want to do is have it print into two columns per page when I go to print it. I'm not even sure where to begin with this because of all thr parameters involved

1. I want to be able to place page breaks after certain blocks of content. Pretty sure I can do this with page-break-after
2. My content is of a dynamic height so I don't think I can calculate how much will fit on one page vs another. So this is really where I'm stumped. I think I can use column-count for this. But I'm not sure how I would do this for print view.

Comment: @media print + column-count

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use **@media print** combined with **column-count**: https://jsfiddle.net/rcpinto/ms5mhw5g/

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam blandit libero eu diam dignissim, eget scelerisque lorem facilisis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vivamus tempor lacus sit amet faucibus sodales. Sed mattis sed felis ut lacinia. Proin pretium augue nec condimentum fermentum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Morbi dignissim vulputate sagittis. Integer diam justo, suscipit a metus sed, facilisis condimentum nibh. Nulla ut accumsan lorem, semper iaculis lectus. Pellentesque a nulla id elit accumsan gravida venenatis at urna. Quisque convallis pellentesque arcu, nec cursus nibh bibendum vel. Praesent porta est sit amet nisi hendrerit bibendum. Sed condimentum, mi vel accumsan pellentesque, magna orci tincidunt nulla, at imperdiet nunc odio nec metus.

Sed ac interdum diam. Donec eget lacus at nisi cursus luctus. Curabitur id quam tellus. Maecenas euismod magna non faucibus lobortis. Morbi varius nunc vitae dictum pellentesque. Proin condimentum porttitor felis, a eleifend lorem viverra at. Quisque lobortis aliquet ex et malesuada. Curabitur mattis elit nec felis efficitur, et tincidunt nulla eleifend. Curabitur ac pulvinar est. Cras semper vitae mauris vitae congue. Nunc sit amet pharetra erat. Sed mattis nunc ac rhoncus euismod. Nam sapien justo, consequat in tortor vitae, vulputate varius diam. Nulla ut velit consequat enim dictum mattis sit amet quis purus. Ut malesuada sapien vel massa dapibus vehicula.

Nunc consequat neque eros, eget consectetur nisl suscipit vel. Nam eget bibendum felis. Donec pellentesque neque ultricies mi imperdiet, eu aliquet velit tempus. Sed ornare tincidunt velit, ac venenatis neque. Fusce condimentum fringilla est, eu malesuada sem faucibus hendrerit. Cras vitae placerat dui. Nam pellentesque tortor ac metus convallis mattis. Pellentesque maximus fermentum porttitor. Vestibulum vehicula enim feugiat, cursus sem non, luctus nisl. Morbi rhoncus dignissim ante et fringilla. Vivamus et augue in orci consectetur faucibus at ut ante. Etiam ipsum massa, semper ut congue a, consequat eu turpis.

Nunc rutrum erat eget lorem vehicula blandit. Vivamus dictum sem diam, semper pellentesque ipsum finibus suscipit. Aenean fringilla dapibus felis, vitae faucibus lectus ultrices a. Etiam et mi eget ex posuere venenatis. Vestibulum efficitur lacinia augue vel scelerisque. Nunc cursus nisl a odio laoreet, sit amet ornare risus faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Ut aliquam egestas justo, id dignissim urna sodales in. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Maecenas ut elementum mi, eget varius sapien. Praesent lectus purus, vehicula euismod fringilla vestibulum, iaculis quis dui. In elit augue, aliquam nec nisi at, vehicula sodales tortor. Proin feugiat blandit eros, at elementum erat.

Etiam mi orci, euismod vitae mollis vel, facilisis in ipsum. Donec porta dolor sed hendrerit tempor. Morbi et eros sit amet lorem tristique luctus sed non felis. Aenean eros dui, hendrerit sed odio quis, cursus sollicitudin felis. Nullam tincidunt sed mi nec dictum. Curabitur velit purus, gravida nec luctus at, vehicula ut lacus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Quisque vitae est eu ipsum scelerisque ullamcorper sit amet commodo elit. Nulla ut commodo tortor.
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="print()" value="Print">
```

CSS:

```
@media print {
  #content {
    column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
  }
}
```

Comment: Inside the div having a long table is not breaking/spanning into the next column... How to handle this case?